# reset form after submittig with ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a registration form (simple html form) that inserts registered users into a database table and this form validates with [jQuery validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) plugin and I need to reset form after successful registration, but I can't and don't know why.

Here is a javascript (jquery) snippet that I use for ajax form submission, that is according to the [jQuery validate way](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

```
submitHandler: function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "registration_form.php",
                    type: "POST",
                    data: $("#form").serialize(),
                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);
                        if(result == '') {
                            $('#form')[0].reset() /*this doesn't work'*/
                            $("#errors").empty(); /*this doesn't work'*/
                        }
                        else {
                            $("#errors").text(result);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
```

And here is my registration_form.php file.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['name']);
$s_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST['s_name']);
$email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
$ticket = htmlspecialchars($_POST['ticket']);

$date = date('d_m_Y');

$valid_email = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);

$table_name = 'registration_' . $date;

if(!$valid_email) {
    die ("Fill the correct email");
}

if((strlen($name) <= 1) || (!$s_name) || (!$email) || (!$ticket)){
    die ("All the fields should be filled");
}

$connect = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password') or die('Connection error');

$create_db = mysqli_query($connect, "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS kultprosvet");

$connect_db = mysqli_select_db($connect, "kultprosvet");

$table = "CREATE TABLE $table_name (
            id INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
            name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            s_name VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
            ticket VARCHAR(100),
            PRIMARY KEY (id)
        )";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT email FROM $table_name");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    if($row['email'] == $email){
        die('this email is already registered');
    };
}

$query_table = mysqli_query($connect,$table);

$query = mysqli_query($connect,"insert into $table_name(name, s_name, email, ticket) values ('$name', '$s_name', '$email','$ticket')");

if(mysqli_errno($connect) > 0){
    echo mysqli_errno($connect). ": " . mysqli_error($connect);
}

mysqli_close($connect);

?>
```

So, now everything works fine, except the form reset.
Can someone show my mistakes and help me to fix this?

P.S. Recently I did the same javascript, but all the data inserted into the .txt file and everything were good, I have no idea why this code doesn't work with database variant.

Comment: Is it your intention to create a new database table for each user that registers? You might end up with problems with hitting a maximum limit on the number of tables that your host sets

Comment: Guess your response is never empty `console.log(result);` - always outputs something right?

Comment: @skobaljic yes, but if form submits console shows only empty row

Comment: @SpacePhoenix only one database creats and table for everyday

Comment: does it enter the check `if(response=='')` ?

Comment: You have a logical fault in your `php` script if the table does not exists it will throw a warning because you are selecting the email from the table to check if it exists before creating the table.

   `$result = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT email FROM $table_name");`

which will throw a warning but will insert the records into the database.

`mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean
given`

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam yeah, you right, I fixed php script, thank you. And `response` instead of `result` shows the same result

Comment: Like Muhammad asks, do you enter the if statement at all?
But what I would do is simply remove the checkbox attribute checked, and set the value of the input fields to empty strings.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line of code to reset all textbox, checkbox elements your values in the form

```
$("input[type=text], textarea").val("");

$('input:checkbox').removeAttr('checked');
```

Comment: Also try var validator = $( "#myform" ).validate();
validator.resetForm();

Comment: no, it doesn't help, the function doesn't see this particular "if" where I want to reset form

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(result == '') { ... }
```

to

```
if(result) { ... // show error } else { // reset }
```

Comment: I have already tried this, the result is the same. Try to write something in console, but no result

Comment: check the type of result and proceed accordingly.

Comment: Of corse I tried to do this, I watched console and only empty row appear, but my "if" doesn't work anyway